# VxWorks allocates more memory than requested

Tags: vxworks

I have a doubt regarding memory allocation in VXWorks.

It looks like VxWorks allocates a few bytes more than requested

Scenario 1:
I request for 64 bytes. Vxworks allocates 66 bytes. Diff of 2 bytes

Scenario 2:
I request for memory of 88 bytes. Vxworks allcoates 96 bytes.Diff of 8 bytes.

Comment: malloc generally does that,  due to space required for metadata.You may additionally have a look at 
                                      
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923157/c-malloc-seems-to-allocate-more-then-im-requesting-array

Comment: Can you please describe two things: the way you are allocating memory and the way you are checking for real buffer size?