# How I return the size of the pointer that I have allocate with malloc?

Tags: c, malloc, sizeof

See this example!

```
int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    int *ptr = malloc(100 * sizeof (int));

    printf("sizeof(array) is %d bytes\n", sizeof(ptr));
}
```

The printf function return only 4 bytes!
What is wrong?

Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Okey guys, I have undertood that sizeof can't return the number of the blocks allocated with malloc, so, how do it? Are there another way?
Thanks again.

Comment: No, there is no portable way to "ask" how much memory was allocated. As @unwind says, you must remember it yourself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get the size of an array from a pointer in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232691/how-can-i-get-the-size-of-an-array-from-a-pointer-in-c)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nothing is wrong. You are asking for, and getting, the size of the pointer on your platform.

It is not in general possible to get the size of the memory block that a pointer points at, you must remember it yourself if you need it later.

Answer (score 2):

On some platforms there is the "msize" function that returns the size of an area allocated by malloc/calloc/strdup. But this is not standard.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot print the size of the memory block you received. Either [`malloc`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malloc) allocates all the memory you requested or it does not (and returns `NULL`).

The [`sizeof()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof) operator does what you request: it tells you the size of the pointer - and the pointer itself occupies 4 bytes in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong, that's the size of any pointer on a 32 bit platform.