# Constructing data pools for components

Tags: c++, stl, components, memory-management, memory-pool

I'm running Windows 7 with a Core Duo.  I've been using Codeblocks for a while now, which I think I have using GNU compiler.

I have (or will have) many component classes that inherit from the abstract class `Component`.  I need help establishing a system to house memory pools for an undetermined amount of component types, each with an undetermined amount of components.  Maybe for the sake of argument the latter is fixed, I can figure out how to change size when abolutely necessary.

Also, conveniently so, each component type has an ID (`unsigned short`) from 0 to whatever with no holes.  Yay!

So, assuming I have some managing clas to keep track of array sizes and things, would something like this work?

```
class Component {};

class FooComponent: public Component {};
class BarComponent: public Component {};
.
.
.

std::vector<Component*> pool_list;

// returns pointer to beginning of pool
Component* foo_pool = MethodToCreateComponentPool(/* Params */)
Component* bar_pool = MethodToCreateComponentPool(/* Params */)

pool_list.push_back(foo_pool);
pool_list.push_back(bar_pool);
```

Maybe put `sizeof(FooComponent)` in for Params.

Then (Where I really start to not know what to do) inside the function do an `malloc( START_COUNT * component_size)`

I have no experience allocating memory like this.  I can easily set up something like

`vector< vector<Component*>* >` or
`map<unsigned short, vector<Component*> >`

but it (is ugly for one) doesn't give me contiguous pools.  I need cache friendly :)

Ideas?  Patterns?  Idioms?  Help?

Comment: What hardware and platform are you targeting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got wrapped up in how I was implementing this and lost track of what I really needed.  Which is basically [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232691/how-can-i-get-the-size-of-an-array-from-a-pointer-in-c).

Thanks.