# How to know size of an array passed from C++ dll to C#

Tags: c#, c++, interop, marshalling

Actually I am using a C++ dll in C# as follows

**MY C++ CODE**

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
    char**  __stdcall hh()
{
 static char* myArray[3] = {"A1", "BB2", "CC3",};
    return myArray;
}
```

**MY C# CODE**

```
[DllImport(@"ourdll.dll",CharSet = CharSet.Ansi,CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]     
      public static extern IntPtr hh();
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IntPtr a = hh();
            int j = 0;
            string[] s=new string[100]; //I want this to be dynamic
           do
           {
               s[j] = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(Marshal.ReadIntPtr(a,4*j));
               j++;
           }
           while(s[j-1] != null);
        }
```

I am unable to get the size of array returned by hh();How can I get the size of array so that my line of code

**string[] s=new string[100]; 
changes to 
string[] s=new string[ACtual Length of array];**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get the size of an array from a pointer in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232691/how-can-i-get-the-size-of-an-array-from-a-pointer-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

You are either going to have to return the size of the array as well (possibly a variable by reference) or you can add a NULL terminator to the list. If you use a NULL terminator you can loop through the array until you find NULL in order to determine the size.

Comment: That I am using in accessing elements of the array,but is there any way via MARSHALLING to know size of array returned.

Comment: The function returns a char**. That has no concept of size for it to be figured out automatically. It is simply a pointer to a pointer to a char. It happens to be pointing at an array of pointers but there is nothing telling the compiler that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to find the length of the array in PInvoke you can use `Marshal.SizeOf(object)` method

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3ybkfb3.aspx)

It works for me for Structures