# passing array to function in c

Tags: c, arrays, function

can someone please help me figure out what i'm doing wrong here? i'm getting inaccurate results here. I seem to be getting the first value in the array each time and i cant seem to figure out what i'm doing incorrectly

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getbillsum ( int price[] );

int main( void )
{
    int itemprice [10];
    int total = 0;
    for (int c=0;c <10;c++ ) //Looping to get item prices
    {
        printf ("\nEnter the price of the item: ");
        scanf (" %d", &itemprice[c]);   
    }
    total = getbillsum (itemprice);
    printf ("%d", total);
    return 0;
}

int getbillsum (int price []) //function to sum the values in array
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<sizeof(price); i++) 
    {
        sum+=price[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. The code you show doesn't compile (`price` is not a known type, so `int getbillsum(price);` won't compile).  This makes people leery of helping you.  Make sure your code compiles (or describe why it won't and why you can't fix it so that it does).

Comment: Sizeof isn't doing what you are expecting here. It's using the variable name which is a pointer to the first element. There is no way to get size of an array by just passing it a pointer so instead pass it a limit for the number of items to consider.

Comment: You seems not paying any effort to debug your own code, at least passing 2 parameter into function which accept only 1 is very obvious problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can't pass arrays to functions in C (well, not as an array anyway). Arrays decay into pointers, the `sizeof` which is always the same (4 for 32 bit systems, 8 for 64 bits).
For more information [see paragraph 2.3 here](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/c-faq/c-2.html_).

The easiest, most common and most reliable way of solving your issue is to pass the length of the array as a second argument:

```
int getbillsum (int *price, size_t len)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<len; ++i)
        sum += price[i];
    return sum;
}
//usage
int main ( void )
{
    int price[10];
    for(int i=0;i<10;++i)
        scanf(" %d", &price[i]);
    printf("Sum: %d\n", getbillsum(price, sizeof(price)/sizeof(*price)));
    return 0;
}
```

You also had a problem in your code: you added the return statement *inside* of your loop.
Just a quick-tip: The sum of an array of ints is not unlikely to be too much for a single int to hold, so I'd change the return-type of `getbillsum` to `long`, too

I've also edited your question, addressing quite a lot of issues considering how short your code was:

```
int getbillsum ( price );//missing type, changed to
int getbillsum ( int price[] );//better would be int getbillsum ( int *price ); but considering your question, left it as array
scanf ("%d", &itemprice[c]);//unsafe, changed it to
scanf (" %d", &itemprice[c]);//add space
total = getbillsum (itemprice,9);//why the second param?
total = getbillsum (itemprice);//to match function prototype
return sum;//moved OUTSIDE of the loop...
```

Comment: @user3218106: You're welcome... please do read the help section of this site, as one of the comments already pointed out. Posting comments saying _thank you_ is discouraged. The _"proper"_ way of thanking someone... and if you do, there's a +2 rep bonus in it for you :-P

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(price)` does not give you the length of the array, but the size of the pointer (`int price[]`), which is probably 4. Also, you immediately return in the first `for` run. Put `return` outside the `for` loop.

You do fix it by supplying the array size, but you never use it. Update your `getbillsum` function:

```
int getbillsum (int price [], int length) //function to sum the values in array
{
   int sum = 0;
   for (int i=0; i<length; i++) 
   {
     sum+=price[i];
   }
   return sum;
}
```

Comment: Is `size` the _mot juste_?  It should be number.  The size would be the number of bytes in the array, so you'd have to scale by the size of an entry in the array.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have seen both `size` and `length` in these cases (ref C#, Java).

Comment: C# and Java have different considerations, and in any case you'd be able to pass the array and access its `.length()` member function — at least, IIRC, that's how Java does it; I don't know about C#, but it is likely similar.  In any case, the rules are different in C. I'd go with `length` as preferable to `size` because in C, size has connotations of `sizeof()` and `size_t` and byte counts.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I don't see any problem with passing length as a `size_t` type, seeing as an array can't be `-1` long, I'd even say an unsigned type is preferable. That's why I used `size_t` in my answer... would it be better, then, if I changed it to `unsigned int` or something?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am all for the semantics, less for language considerations, but I agree with you. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to posted answers, you can consider a technique suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/232719/2549281) answer.

**Edit** Quoted from comment

> it's non-standard, dangerous (think of overflow, forgetting to
>   dereference at the correct offset and the like), and you should not
>   try this

In your case it will be something like that :

```
void *p = calloc(sizeof(itemprice) + sizeof(unsigned long int),1));
*((unsigned long int*)p) = 10;
```

quote from linked answer

> n is now stored at *((unsigned long int*)p)

Your getbillsum will look like that now (did not compile it, consider it as pseudocode)

```
 int getbillsum (void* p)
 {
     int* price = p+sizeof(unsigned long int);
     unsigned long int size = *p;
     int sum = 0;

     for (int i=0; i<size; i++) 
     {
        sum+=price[i];
     }
     return sum;
 }
```

Comment: Please, read the linked answer thoroughly, first: this _"solution"_ depends on non-standard behaviour, and therefore might not compile at all... it's a hack, that is _completely unnecessary_ What's so hard about keeping track of the size on-the-fly? Or even passing the length @ calltime?

Comment: Perhaps, but SO aims to be a repo of Q&A formatted relevant, valid and _correct_ code... your answer just states _"you could do this"_ without it mentioning the fact that it's non-standard, dangerous (thing of overflow, forgetting to dereference at the correct offset and the like), and you _should not try this_. The only thing this approach is good for is to check if you understand pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Warning added