# passing 2d array to function with in c

Tags: c

Is there any way to pass 2D array to a function as `function(arr,m,n)` 
and the function defenition as `void function(int **p,int m,int n)`
ie, Without explicitly specifying array size ??

Comment: In short: No, there isn't.

Comment: possible duplicate of [passing 2D array to function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-2d-array-to-function)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232691/how-can-i-get-the-size-of-an-array-from-a-pointer-in-c

Comment: No. There is no way to pass the 2D array to a function Without explicitly specifying array size. for both 1D and 2d array you need to pass the array size to a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Let us C](http://www.flipkart.com/let-c-13th/p/itmdyueqvbspzywn?pid=9788183331630&icmpid=reco_pp_same_book_1&ppid=9788183333276) has a good explanation about how to pass two D array as parameter.

I usually use these two ways for passing 2D array as parameter. But you need to specify the size explicitly.

```
void display1(int q[][4],int row,int col){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<col;j++)
            printf("%d",q[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void display2(int (*q)[4],int row,int col){
    int i,j;
    int *p;
    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        p=q+i;
        for(j=0;j<col;j++)
            printf("%d",*(p+j));
        printf("\n");
    }
}
int main()
{
   int a[3][4]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,6};
   display1(a,3,4);
   display2(a,3,4);
}
```

Comment: It's probably worth noting that in C99, this also works with variable-length arrays.